# What is $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2-y^2} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the following limit 
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2-y^2}$$

This question has been bugging me for some time. Couldn't find it anywhere on the Internet

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Does this limit exist? Every punctured neighborhood of $(0,0)$ contains points where the expression isn't defined.

Comment: Simon S's point is that the function is not defined at any point on the lines y= x or y= -x.

Comment: I will answer on condition that you show what you have tried,or include some background or details.

Comment: i think the limit is 0
switch to polar coordinates and you will see it. you can also simplify the equation: x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2+xy +y^2)
good luck

Comment: @SimonS: Not all textbooks agree on this, but it's fairly common when defining limits to require only that every punctured neighborhood contains some points from the domain $D_f$, and then only taking those points into account. (I.e., points not in the domain are simply ignored.)

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel a common factor:
$$\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)}{(x-y)(x+y)}=\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x+y} $$
(This also continuously extends the function to most of the line $x=y$).

Along any straight line $(x,y)=(at,bt)$, $t\to 0$, this is $\frac{a^2 +ab+b^2}{a+b}\cdot t$ and tends to $0$. But this of course does not work for the case $b=-a$ where the expression is undefined.
However, convergence along straight lines is not convergence!
If we consider $(x,y)=(t+t^2,-t)$, $t\to 0$, we arrive at
$$\frac{(t+t^2)^2+(t+t^2)(-t)+(-t)^2}{t+t^2-t} =\frac{t^2+t^3+t^4}{t^2}=1+t+t^2\to 1$$

Comment: The answer is given as 3/2